# Which package contains the "cpupower" utility/command on Fedora 25 or 28 or in Qubes OS?

Tags: fedora, qubes

I need the `cpupower` command, if only to see if it works at all in Qubes OS 4.0 whose dom0 is running Fedora 25 and whose VMs are running Fedora 28(and other versions, depending on what TemplateVMs you have installed).

I tried(to no avail):

```
sudo qubes-dom0-update --action=search cpupower    
sudo qubes-dom0-update --action=search cpufreq
sudo qubes-dom0-update --action=search power
sudo qubes-dom0-update --action=search cpu
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Fedora (and Qubes OS), the package name which provides the `cpupower` command is `kernel-tools`

**Examples:**

In Qubes OS 4.0 's dom0:

```
[ctor@dom0 ~]$ sudo qubes-dom0-update kernel-tools
...
Installed:
  kernel-tools.x86_64 4.13.16-100.fc25                         kernel-tools-libs.x86_64 4.13.16-100.fc25

[ctor@dom0 ~]$ sudo cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: Not Available
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: Not Available
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
Not Available
  available cpufreq governors: Not Available
  Unable to determine current policy
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency:  Unable to call to kernel
  boost state support:
    Supported: yes
    Active: yes
```

In a Fedora 28 VM (Qubes OS 4.0):

```
[user@dev01-w-s-f-fdr28 ~]$ sudo dnf install kernel-tools
...
Installed:
  kernel-tools.x86_64 4.17.19-200.fc28                                          
  kernel-tools-libs.x86_64 4.17.19-200.fc28                                     

[user@dev01-w-s-f-fdr28 ~]$ sudo cpupower frequency-info
analyzing CPU 0:
  no or unknown cpufreq driver is active on this CPU
  CPUs which run at the same hardware frequency: Not Available
  CPUs which need to have their frequency coordinated by software: Not Available
  maximum transition latency:  Cannot determine or is not supported.
Not Available
  available cpufreq governors: Not Available
  Unable to determine current policy
  current CPU frequency: Unable to call hardware
  current CPU frequency:  Unable to call to kernel
  boost state support:
    Supported: no
    Active: no
```

Perhaps this is not the way in Qubes OS ...
See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117772/306023) answer if you're interested in pure Fedora (ie. NOT Qubes OS).